# GitHub for Windows: commit size

Tags: git, github

When committing in [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/), is there any way to see the total size of the files that are being committed?

[image]

I am aware that we can see the repository size on the GitHub website.

Comment: Can I ask why? If you're looking to predict how much data will be sent to the server see [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4179842/94928), but that doesn't necessarily equate to the size of all of your committed files on disk.

Comment: @heavyd Thanks for the link, the main motivation is spotting data files, binaries and PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to see the total size of the files that are being committed in GitHub for Windows.